# xstring and on-the-fly creation of command

Tags: xstring, bidi

I am using bidishadowtext in a class file I am using. This package doesn't allow any line breaking characters in its text, so I was trying to get smart, and defining a command that, given a title with a `\nl` inside, would split the string in two, apply `bidishadowtext` to both, and join them together again.

For this, I found `xstring`, and because I am crazy, I decided to try my luck. This was how far I've come:

```
\usepackage{xstring}  
\def\nl{!!NL!!}
\verbtocs{\mynl}|}}\\\bidishadowtext{\textsc{|
\verbtocs{\myEnd}|}}|
\verbtocs{\myBegin}|\bidishadowtext{\textsc{|

\newcommand{\formatTitle}[1]{
   \IfSubStr{#1}{!!NL!!}{
      \def\myTitle{\StrSubstitute{#1}{!!NL!!}{\mynl}}
      \StrExpand[3]{\myTitle}{\xTitle}
      \scancs{\theTitle}{\myBegin\xTitle\myEnd}
      \theTitle
 }%
 {%
   \bidishadowtext{\textsc{#1}}
 }
}
```

I am happy both with direct solutions to my original problems, or fixes to this code (I would love to learn how to solve this issue too).

**EDIT:** this is to be used in the implementation of a `\chapter` redefinition, so I do not want final users to really understand what is going on.

Comment: I think this would be more successful with expl3 / LaTeX3 features

Comment: Completely unaware of LaTeX3 :)

Comment: You didn't provide an example so it is difficult to know what you really want to achieve. But why don't you do something like `\bidishadowtext{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}blblb\\ blbllb\end{tabular}}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am developing a class file, and want to this code to be used by a `chapter` command. Don't want to ask users to put a tabular inside a chapter call :-)

Comment: You can put the wrapper tabular in your code and your user would simply have to enter `blblb\\blbllb` -- check in article.cls how \@author is used in \maketitle.

Comment: Ah, that looks a good approach. Will try. Thanks @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Almost good to go. My current problem is that it is messing up with its bounding box, and not getting middle centered (vertically) on the Tikz. Seems to be `bidishadowtext` fault.

Comment: Now usiing `parbox` instead of `tabular` and working 99% well.